# Looking for a story featuring Pegasus, two boys and a girl

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this book 6-7 years ago. It was a series with over three books.

What I remember:

- There was something about "the Flame of Olympus"
- The main character is a girl
- The setting was most likely in New York because the Empire State Building is mentioned (or some skyscraper)
- Pegasus falls on the roof
- The girl has to run from the government and the bad guys
- Boy 1 joins later on
- Boy 2 is in a hospital, but also joins them

Is there any book that matches this description?

### ***It is NOT Percy Jackson.***

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The Flame of Olympus](https://www.simonandschuster.com/books/The-Flame-of-Olympus/Kate-OHearn/Pegasus/9781442444102) (Book #1 of Pegasus) by Kate O'Hearn (2013 - Simon and Schuster)?

> A young girl, a winged horse, and an Olympian war make for an
> adventurous start to an exciting trilogy.
>
> When Pegasus crashes onto a Manhattan roof during a terrible storm,
> thirteen-year-old Emily’s life changes forever. Suddenly allied with a
> winged horse she’d always thought was mythical, Emily is thrust into
> the center of a fierce battle between the Roman gods and a terrifying
> race of multiarmed stone warriors called the Nirads. Emily must team
> up with a thief named Paelen, the goddess Diana, and a mortal boy
> named Joel in order to return Pegasus to Olympus and rescue the gods
> from a certain death.
>
> Along the way, Emily and her companions will fight monsters, run from
> a government agency that is prepared to dissect Pegasus, and even fly
> above the Manhattan skyline—all as part of a quest to save Olympus
> before the Olympic flame burns out.

[image]